# dynamic image source?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm entirely new to jQuery and am trying to use a plugin carousel, however it is a bit confusing. I have it installed now, and I am trying to get rid of it's bottom scroll bar and automate it. The code to make enable auto according to the manual is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("#carousel").rcarousel({
            auto: {
                enabled: true,
                interval: 3000,
                direction: "next"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

but it appears that is not going to work.
If there is any other info you need please let me know, so the goals here are:

1. remove scroll bar
2. automate the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

According to the rcarosel [Configuration](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration) - adding the property `auto` with a value in miliseconds should do the trick for your autoscrolling.  I'm not sure where you pulled the code you posted from, but this should create an rScroller or whatever with an auto scroll.

```
$("#carousel").rcarousel({
                auto: 3000 
              });
```

The scroll bar is likely appearing because your JavaScript is failing at some point, so the element remains with a scroll bar. Mind you, this effect is desirable for when users have JavaScript disabled, they are still able to view the content.

Comment: Maybe, but we're not psychic :p Also, your DOM ready function is a little weird, it might not be a problem but I usually use `$(document).ready(function(){ });`

Comment: i changed the dom ready but nothing happened so im guessing it is in the wrong place, here is the end of the code:

(in question)

Comment: yeah i was trying to edit it, but i guess i cant do the code snippet thing in comments, itll be up there in 5 seconds.

Comment: fml. i inserted it into your answer -.- maybe i need to sleep. it wont let me delete it :/